# Amazon s3 image cache - updated logo, it updated on my phone but not others

Tags: javascript, html, caching, amazon-s3, frontend

I'm very new to coding and i was told to change the logo on our website and app. I've changed the logo image and kept the same name so that i wouldn't have to touch the code the problem is that it's been 5 days and when i checked on the phones i had in our company which is about 5 different smartphones, i checked that the logo was changed. when we were in a meeting today and they check their phones to see if the logo changed and it didn't!

I've been searching Amazon s3 image cache on Google but i can't really understand who this could have happened.

can someone pls explain this to me

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you "Make public" your newly uploaded image? If yes, do you use amazon cloudfront to host your website

Comment: No i didn't make it public and we don't use cloudfront

Comment: Try making it public first and see whether it works

Comment: Great i posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it public in your s3 website after uploading. Because by default when you upload some content to s3 bucket, it will be not visible.

You can change this setting by refering the below url. In order to "Make Public" by default, so you don't need to repeat work.

http://g14n.info/2016/04/s3-bucket-public-by-default/